# ¿Quién le manda?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, modismos

What would be a good translation for "¿quién le manda?" As in: "Su hermano le ha metido en muchas broncas. ¿Quién le manda tener un hermano asi?" The source is Mexican.

Answer (score 3):

The bottom line of this expression is that all the blame is taken by the actor for any resulting misfortune.

When we say **¿Quién le manda tener un hermano así?** the implication is that the fault is his/her/theirs for having such a brother. Although in this case, we understand no one is liable for having a sibling; they're blaming the actor nonetheless.

An easier to understand example would be:

—¡Me acaba de picar una abeja!
—¿Y quién te manda jugar con el panal?

Now cause and effect are clear, the actor got stung by a bee. But the blame is on them because they where playing with the hive.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Krauss's great answer, we can add that the meaning of "mandar" could be that appearing under (5) or (6) [here](https://dle.rae.es/mandar) (make somebody do something, force somebody to do something, entrust somebody to do something).

This translation would apply more easily to the case of the bee, the implication being that nobody has forced the person to play with the beehive and that the decision to do so was solely theirs: And who has forced you to meddle with the beehive?

However, in the case of having a troublesome brother, nobody can actually be blamed for that, so the question is even funnier, as if having such a brother could be one's responsibility while nobody can actually choose to have a certain type of brother. One's willingness and fault could be pointed out if the relationship were of a more voluntary kind, for example:

- Su amigo/novia lo ha metido en muchos problemas. ¿Quién le manda tener un amigo/una novia así? (Everybody can actually choose their friends or their partners)